# Intersecting Frustum

Tags: unity-game-engine, geometry, arcore, frustum

I am trying to find a way to determine whether two frusta intersect and, if so, how big of an intersection that is (example 100% if the two frusta are in exact same location, 0% if they don't touch).

I have the position, volume and all sort of data about the two frusta, I just have no idea how to use it. I took a look at the Separating Axis Theorem for collision detection but I can't figure out exactly whether it's what I'm looking for.

Does anybody have any suggestion on the direction to go?

Answer (score 1):

The SAT will only tell you if they are touching.  It won't be able to give you a percentage overlap.   To calculate the frusta overlap percentage, I think you will need to calculate the volume of the poyhedron created by intersecting the frusta and divide by the volume of the "main" frustum.

Calculating the intersection of the frusta will tell you if they are overlapping.  One way to do it is to build a bsp out of each one, and do a CSG Intersection operation.

Once you have the interesection polyhedron, you can calculate its volume by splitting it up into tetrahedrons and adding up all the volumes of the tetrahedrons.  There are academic papers out there that do tetrahedralization directly from the BSP representation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that sounds way out of my math / geometry skills to build a reliable system that does what you said :)

Comment: What do you need this for?  Maybe there's an alternative.